# File upload in ionic

Tags: file-upload, ionic-framework

> How to upload any type of files like doc, pdf, image etc. in ionic? 
>   can anyone tell me the right solution?

Thanks

Comment: @Corbin i have used file transfer plugin and camera plugin but camera file allow only image file. But i want all types of file should be uploaded

Answer (score 2):

you can use cordova file transfer plugin for uploading and downloading files from ionic application.Below is the link of its doc:-

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/

Note:- It won't work in browser.But works fine in device and emulator

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded a sample project in [github](https://github.com/anilkumar007/File_Transfer)for uploading different type's of files in a server.

Have a look and reply me if you have any queries

Comment: I am not able to find filepath. As i saw your code, filepath is always null. and one more thing the selected file is in encoded format right?

Comment: If you not find the file path means, How you are going to saying that the selected file is encoded form

Comment: For me it is showing the file path

Comment: cordova.file.external* gives null in android mobile 4.4. and How will know user select file from external??

Comment: I am printing the file path in consoller